# Get all folders from Composite

Tags: c#

I'm creating a tree structure of a given folder (only folders no files) 
also i return the security permission of each folder and add it to a list

Now how can i Loop through this composite and get all items and sub items

```
 public abstract class FolderComponent:IEnumerable
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string[]> Rules { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddFolder(FolderComponent folderComponent);
    public abstract IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    public abstract void AssignRules();
}

public class Folder : FolderComponent
{
    public IList<FolderComponent> FolderComponents { get; set; }

    public Folder(string path)
    {
        FullName = path;
        FolderComponents = new List<FolderComponent>();
        Rules = new List<string[]>();
    }

    public override void AddFolder(FolderComponent folderComponent)
    {
        FolderComponents.Add(folderComponent);
    }

    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return FolderComponents.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override void AssignRules()
    {
        // some code
        string[] rules = new string[]{"Read","Write","Execute"};
        Rules.Add(rules);
    }

}

public class Program
{
    private static FolderComponent GetFolders(string path)
    {
        FolderComponent folder = new Folder(path);
        folder.AssignRules();
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            folder.AddFolder(GetFolders(directory));
        }
        return folder;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        FolderComponent folder = GetFolders(@"C\:Test");
        // How can i loop though all folder structure inside folder?


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that i have to rework the method 'IEnumerator GetEnumerator()' or rework the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something like this with your `Folder` class:

```
FolderComponent folders = GetFolders(@"C\:Test");
foreach (var folder in folders) { Console.WriteLine(folder.FullName); }
```

and get the full directory tree printed, then the `GetEnumerator` method needs to have logic to traverse the tree.  For example

```
    public override IEnumerator<FolderComponent> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Return the current element
        yield return this;

        // Work through the collection of components in this folder ...
        foreach (var component in FolderComponents)
        {
            // ... and traverse all the subfolders in each component.  
            // Note that this recursively calls this GetEnumerator
            // method on the subfolders to work down the tree.
            foreach (var subfolder in component)
            {
                yield return subfolder;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a method to your FolderComponent class and implement that
see if that can do the thing:

```
 public abstract class FolderComponent : IEnumerable
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string[]> Rules { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddFolder(FolderComponent folderComponent);
    public abstract IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    public abstract void AssignRules();
    public abstract List<FolderComponent> GetAllItems();
}

public class Folder : FolderComponent
{
    public IList<FolderComponent> FolderComponents { get; set; }

    public Folder(string path)
    {
        FullName = path;
        FolderComponents = new List<FolderComponent>();
        Rules = new List<string[]>();
    }

    public override void AddFolder(FolderComponent folderComponent)
    {
        FolderComponents.Add(folderComponent);
    }

    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return FolderComponents.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override void AssignRules()
    {
        // some code
        string[] rules = new string[] { "Read", "Write", "Execute" };
        Rules.Add(rules);
    }

    public override List<FolderComponent> GetAllItems()
    {
        var resultItems = new List<FolderComponent> {this};
        foreach (var folderComponent in FolderComponents)
        {
            resultItems.AddRange(folderComponent.GetAllItems());
        }                        
        return resultItems;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static FolderComponent GetFolders(string path)
    {
        FolderComponent folder = new Folder(path);
        folder.AssignRules();
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            folder.AddFolder(GetFolders(directory));
        }
        return folder;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {

        FolderComponent rootfolder = GetFolders(@"D:\4Share");
        var allItems = rootfolder.GetAllItems();
        foreach (var folderComponent in allItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folderComponent.FullName);                
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add a list of folder type (children).

```
FolderComponent Parent;
List<FolderComponent> children;
```

And add a child when u find a folder inside specific folder. You can add parent for backward processing as well.

```
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
foreach (var directory in directoryInfo)
{
    FolderComponent newSubFolder = new FolderComponent();
    newSubFolder.Parent = this;
    // get whatever you want like name, permissions etc.
    children.Add(newSubFolder);
}
```

You need something like this in your code (depends on implementation)

```
PrintFolders()
{
    foreach(var child in children)
         child.PrintFolders();

    Console.WriteLine(FolderName);
}
```

Comment: This part is already done 'please see my recursive method private static FolderComponent GetFolders(string path) '. my question is more about after this process how can i retrieve them

Comment: foreach (var folder in folders) { Console.WriteLine(folder.FullName); }

Comment: It prints only the main level and first sub level

Comment: you need to do it recursively, this can be either acheived by making a function in FolderComponent or in your main,